# Неработоспособность сети при чужом DNS

Tags: сеть, dns

Сегодня столкнулся с интересной особенностью местного провайдера.

Итак, внешний адрес я получаю от провайдера через DHCP, а DNS я пробил гугловские `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`. Все работало, пока у провайдера не случилась какая-то поломка (писало, что сетевой кабель не подключен). После устранения поломки интернет у меня пропал. Т.е. внешний адрес я получал, а вот пинги никуда не уходили. Ни на `8.8.8.8` ни на адрес шлюза провайдера.

Проблема решилась когда я заменил гугловские сервера дефолтными, получаемые от провайдера.

У меня вопрос: что это было? Какой-то хитрый алгоритм авторизации через DNS?

Comment: если воспроизвести не получится, то я бы сказал, что это просто совпадение...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не получается. Но заметил, что теперь внешний адрес выдается из совершенно другой подсети